# Can a question "go hot" multiple times within three seconds?

Tags: bug, hot-questions, revisions-list

I answered [this code review post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/244185/120114) and noticed in [the history](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/244185/revisions) 23 distinct entries  of **Became Hot Network Question**. The first 20 timestamps show 2020-06-20 01:55:14Z and the last three show 2020-06-20 01:55:17Z.

[image: latest HNQ entries]

[image: first HNQ entries]

Is this a bug?