# How hot? Double hot (bug resurfaced?)

Tags: bug, hot-questions, timeline, regression

> [image]
> [Link](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/84931/timeline)

From: [Very hot network questions found](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327889/392799)

Marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Something broke again?

Comment: from the answer: *There is a chance that this will not completely eliminate the issue under high load, and we may need to add an UPDLOCK hint to the query as well. Decided to go incrementally with this, and will add the lock later if needed.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Very hot network questions found](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327889/very-hot-network-questions-found)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a question "go hot" multiple times within three seconds?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349784/can-a-question-go-hot-multiple-times-within-three-seconds?noredirect=1&lq=1) - Find with:   https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1232023/entered-hnq-more-than-once?num=500

Comment: Stay away from that so as not to get yourself burnt.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens no, we don't close question as duplicates of bug reports or feature requests marked as completed. (Assuming of course the bug is back.)

Comment: @Rob see comment for Pierre. (anyone: please let me know if this question is closed and I'll reopen)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating makes sense, vote retracted ...

Comment: @Sha not only is linking all the [**recent** (unfixed) reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346518/why-has-this-question-become-hot-twice-within-a-few-seconds-of-interval?noredirect=1&lq=1) useful, but the one ***claimed*** fixed clearly was not; it should be untagged and reopened. What if we get another few more BRs the same as the above question this week, do we leave them all open too.

Comment: @Rob removing the status completed tag is very rare, and also wrong. The bug **was fixed**, but returned at some point later on. Further same reports will be closed as duplicates of the one without status completed.

Comment: Which is what I've indicated.

Comment: "The concern with this is that questions right on the edge of the list may pop on and off the list several times, as frequently as every fifteen minutes, thus cluttering up the history." - Source: [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350423/where-can-i-see-at-what-time-a-hot-network-question-lost-its-hot-network-questi?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1173177_350423) to question: "[Where can I see at what time a hot network question lost its “hot network question” status?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350423/282094)".